how to turn Bigquery "session mode" on from within local VS Code?
Anyone know how to turn Bigquery "session mode" on from within local VS Code? By the way, I need to create temp table, which needs the session mode to be on.

Hi , could you please elaborate more on your requirements ?

@SouravDutta, I followed this link and I was able to set up running Bigquery from local VS Code.  In google chrome, I can turn on the session mode and create a temp table in bigquery, but I don't know how to do the same from within VS Code.   https://developers.lseg.com/en/article-catalog/article/run-google-bigquery-sql-with-vscode
